# How do I format BetsAPI date time to local date time

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I am trying to figure out what datetime format BetsAPI uses and how to convert it to local date time.  I get the information through a JSON file.

Sample Code: updated_at is what I am trying to convert.

```
"schedule": {
                **"updated_at": "1557235827",**
                "sp": {
                    "main": [
                        {
                            "odds": "2.000"
                        },
                        {
                            "odds": "1.800"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **updated_at** property is just a classic **timestamp**.

If you parse **1557235827** in a conversion website such as [this one](https://www.epochconverter.com/), you will see the datetime in a more readable format : *GMT: Tuesday 7 May 2019 13:30:27*.

Comment: Thank you, that was a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTimeOffset` to convert unix time to `DateTime`

```
var update_at = 1557235827; 
var updateAtTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(update_at).DateTime;
```